# What are some old-world alternatives or precursors to 'WTF' (expressions of frustration or surprise)?

Tags: popular-refrains, synonyms, rhetoric, exclamations

Such as 'what on Earth' or 'what in the world', etc.  I'm trying to come up with a list of witty alternatives.

Note: I'm not looking for alternatives to the letters W, T, and F.  I'm looking for alternative phrases such as the ones I listed above.

Comment: This might get closed as it's subjective and there is no right answer... but i think It's a good thread :)

Comment: Community Wiki? Anyone?

Comment: Yeah, this could definitely be a Wiki question.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain...

Comment: Wiki maybe. Certainly not what I would want to see in the main EL&U site. This isn't urbandictionary.

Comment: Sorry to be daft, but where do I find the community wiki? Is that another name for the Metas site or is it something completely different?

Comment: @teylyn: There isn't a place where you read "all the community wiki posts" I guess... They were talking about it in the chat once...

Comment: @teylyn — on SE, "Community Wiki" is a property of questions/answers. If the property is set, anyone can edit anything, and nobody accrues any reputation.

Comment: Thanks Alleanno and Martha. That helps. Pity there is no way to easily browse through these posts. Would it not make sense to create a CW tag?

Comment: @Alenanno, et al - if someone told you that you can't read/browse/search just CW posts, they were incorrect. [Here's your link](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+closed%3A0).

Answer (score 13):

**WTD** is quite old (What the Devil). Here's an early example from [1727](http://books.google.com/books?id=lIQUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22what%20the%20devil?%22&hl=en&ei=KHXpTcjnNqXt0gGtuuSqAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=%22what%20the%20devil?%22&f=false):

[image]

Comment: I'd forgotten about that phrase.  Also, the play by John Vanbrugh that you linked to looks quite hilarious. :)

Comment: Makes me think of "What the deuce?"

Answer (score 7):

How about:

> How in Tarnation!?
>   What in Thunder?
>   I'll be jiggered!

Maybe you would like:

> How on earth?
>   How in Creation?

Comment: "How in tarnation?" -- that's a good one.

Comment: Another one: "what the fiddlesticks?"

Comment: @Dominique - I learned a while back that "tarnation" comes from "tarnal damnation", where "tarnal" is a corruption of "eternal".

Comment: @MT_Head. I had wondered about that. I think I had only every heard it used by Yosemite Sam in the cartoons.

Answer (score 4):

> **blimey**
>   exclamation Brit., informal
>   used to express one's surprise, excitement, or alarm.
>   ORIGIN late 19th century: altered form of *(God) blind (or blame) me!*

Answer (score 2):

My grandmother used to say *"well, I'll go to the foot of our stairs!"*

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked "Well, shut my mouth wide open!", as exclaimed by Dot in an episode of Animanics.

Comment: This reminds me of "well, slap my thigh and call me Sally!" and similar phrases.  "Well, cover me in sugar and call me a donut" is another one.  A quick Google search will bring up lots of variations.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of only one:

> Well, I never!

Answer (score 1):

There is a common phrase that borrows a word from the French and is an alternate to "[What the Devil?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/what-are-some-funny-old-world-alternatives-to-wtf/28477#28477)":

> What in the deuce?

Comment: I always heard that 'deuce' was just a euphemism for 'devil'.

Answer (score 1):

An old favourite is "lo!" as in "lo and behold!" but also used on its own.

It has been around since the first millennium and was also used in the epic poem Beowulf. See also Moby Dick for plenty of examples.

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/lo-and-behold.html

Answer (score 1):

In Australia, the typical exclamation would be, simply, "*Oi*!" (the roots of which can probably be found in Cockney English). Another one, made famous by the late Steve Irwin, is "*Crikey*!"

Answer (score 0):

I am partial to "odds bodkins" and "sweet mother of pearl!"