# One word to say to someone who's being in a state they're usually not (or doing something they never did)?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, expression-choice

In my native language, there is a singe word to say to someone who apparently are doing something they never did before, or being in state they never were before. Like:

> Mr. X had always been late. But today he came on time.
>
> Mr. Y said, "[...], you're always late before."

Or:

> Ms. A had never kept in touch with Mr. B. One day she dropped him a line all of a sudden.
>
> Mr. B said, "[...]. What makes you call me? I thought you'd forgotten we're friends."

Or:

> A student had always been so much lazy. But one day he finished all of his homework and listened to the teacher during the whole class.
>
> So the teacher said, "[...]. You're being diligent. You usually are not."

I know that this condition is described by means as in *you are being diligent*, or *you're not usually like this.*. Or perhaps *this is not you.*?

But I need an expression for that (one-word expression, if possible), and I can only think of these:

> - How odd!
> - For the first time.
> - What happened? (Or what's happening?)
> - Hey, is this really you?

Well, I don't think I'm doing this right.

**P.S.**: What we say to this person (according to my mother tongue, Indonesian): *Tumben!*.

**P.P.S.**: I'm looking for an *insinuating* or *joking* expression, not swear-word interjections like the ones in the suggested possible duplicate.

Comment: Which word in your language did you have in mind?

Comment: My mother tongue is Indonesian, we say, *Tumben!*. I don't know if there is an English word for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some old-world alternatives or precursors to 'WTF' (expressions of frustration or surprise)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/what-are-some-old-world-alternatives-or-precursors-to-wtf-expressions-of-frus). It's a bit "dated" today, but the explanation *"**Well I never!**"* is a close match to OP's *precise* sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Why is it *Will I never!*? How's that possibly a close match to my sense?

Comment: @Safira: It's *"**Well** I never!"* Which is effectively short for something like *"I never saw [or heard of] such a thing before in my life!"* There probably isn't any idiomatic word/expression in English for *"**He** never did such a thing before!"*, because the whole point of the exclamation is to indicate *surprise on the part of the speaker*. Although it's getting a bit "dated", in the contexts you have cited, *"**Well** I never!"* or an equivalent is what a native would say (it's more a matter of *"**I** am surprised!"*, rather than *"**You** are surprising!"*).

Comment: Are you saying that the *Well I never* is close to WTF in the suggested possible duplicate you just mentioned? I'm not looking for swear-word expressions.(?) Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A person acting against their perceived tendency is behaving [*uncharacteristically*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uncharacteristically). When the person's behavior is undesirable we may say *they are not themselves*. But the given examples are of behavior desirable to the speaker, and a phrase that might be used is [*what a pleasant surprise!*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+a+pleasant+surprise&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwhat%20a%20pleasant%20surprise%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWhat%20a%20pleasant%20surprise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhat%20a%20pleasant%20surprise%3B%2Cc0) But this phrase has other uses; it's not only for when a person behaves uncharacteristically.

Another phrase that focuses more on the person: If the speaker desires an explanation for the unexpected but desirable behavior, they may get their answer by (humorously and informally) asking the other person *Are you feeling ok?* The speaker may also humorously refer to the emotions the desired behavior promoted in them with *I'm shocked* or *I'm touched*. Some speakers jokingly challenge their senses with *Do my eyes [ears, for the phone call] deceive me?* or reality with *Can it be (true)?* Others joke about the identity of the other person with *Who are you, and what have you done with Mr. X?*

If the person has changed from undesirable behavior to desirable, the speaker might ask *Why the [change of heart](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+change+of+heart)?* The speaker may further remark that the change is [*welcome*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=welcome+change&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwelcome%20change%3B%2Cc0).

As shown we have many expressions for unexpected behavior in a person, but I can think of no one-word interjection used strictly in this context.

Comment: +1. This is the answer I need. Perfectly match to my sense. :)

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat similar to dingo_dan's *uncharacteristically*, the phrase **[out of character](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/out-of-character)** is often used to mean

> not typical of the apparent character of a person or thing

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of one word that would fit, but a short expression that may fit in certain situtations is *What a surprise!* If you are speaking narratively, you can use *To my surprise...*

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#id/en/Tumben) gives an additional multi-word suggestion, *Oddly enough...*

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but it was promoted to me and I think it's worth commenting that English has an idiom for this: *[turn over a new leaf](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-over-a-new-leaf)*

> Mr. X, you've *turned over a new leaf*!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your examples, I might very well simply make that one word "wow". For example:

> Mr. Y said, "Wow, you've always been late before."`

This is a bit of a cheat though because "wow" doesn't mean "uncharacteristically": it is an interjection indicating surprise at something that has happened. There are many other interjections that can indicate surprise; "wow" is just the one that came to mind and has the virtue of being very short and widely understood.